# Riesz Representation Theorem in Wikipedia vs. Rudin's RCA

Tags: measure-theory, hilbert-spaces, riesz-representation-theorem

In Rudin's Real & Complex Analysis theorem 2.14, the Riesz representation theorem gives (in my very rough phrasing) an injection from linear functionals on a space to positive Borel measures which represent the functionals, in a sense.

In [Wikipedia's article about said theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_representation_theorem), however, the correspondence is stated between continuous linear functionals on a Hilbert space and the Hilbert space itself.

Trying to reconcile the two, there must be then a one-to-one isomorphism between the set of measures and the Hilbert space: but what is it? Does every point in the Hilbert space define a measure and vice versa?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Markov%E2%80%93Kakutani_representation_theorem

Comment: To elaborate on the comment above: There are many results (about 2-3 of which are (more or less) completely different as you noted) which are called the "Riesz representation theorem". But from the context where they are used, it is usually clear, which version is intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, there are different "Riesz representation theorems".

- The Hilbert space version (pretty easy to prove) gives a natural correspondence between bounded linear functionals and the elements  of the Hilbert space.
- The representation of linear functionals on the spaces $C(K)$ (continuous functions on a compact space), $C_c(X)$ (continuous with compact support) and $C_0(X)$ (continuous and vanishing at infinity) involves measures and is considerably harder.

Comment: But is there a correspondence between maps on $C_c(X)$ and measures? Something like $f \mapsto f d\mu$ where $d\mu$ is e.g. the Lebesgue measure? The reason I am asking is because many times Rudin would mention the second theorem you enlist in order to justify a result that resembles more the _first_ theorem you enlist.

Comment: Yes, this is one of forms of RRT, [stated here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RieszRepresentationTheorem.html)